# Pyqt5 Fixed window size in several monitor(environment)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm making a opinion mining system based on web crawling.

Through Qtdesigner and pyqt5, I made own gui .

throguh this GUI, I want to provide my system to other person.

but my Gui sometimes shows other way (crack or very small size)

I think difference environment such as monitor size (resolution) made this problem.

I think fix-sized based on inches can be a solution of this problem.

Are there other way to fixed my GUI in other computers same as develop environment?

thanks

Comment: Your current question is too broad, but I suspect that is the way you distribute your application, you could indicate relevant information regarding OS that bring you problems, etc.

Comment: You can make your application fullscreen, do `.setMaximized()` or `.setFullScreen()`